# Installing Eclipse for PHP and Selenium

Tags: java, php, eclipse, selenium

I have used Selenium Standalone server and have written tests in PHP and Node.js; Did not use an IDE (used SublimeText).

I have a requirement to start writing tests in Java using Eclipse and Selenium.

Primarily I'm a PHP Developer, and I notice separate downloads "Eclipse for PHP" and "Eclipse for Java".

I'd love to use an Eclipse geared towards PHP since it's the primary language that I code for, however I'd also like it (the Eclipse app) to be ready, willing, and able to invoke the Selenium Standalone server and drive automated browser tests.

I checked via questions/tags and didn't see much luck based on what and how I'm looking to use Eclipse.  Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here after nearly a week. I installed the standard Java IDE for Eclipse and then added the Eclipse PDT Tools. Done and Done. I didn't think the process would be that easy, but it was. I simply got tripped up by the available options from the initial download page.